ffmpeg fialing with "could not find coded parameters"
running ffmpeg -i in a C# console app using Process, for certain files, the process gets stuck and runs forever
        var oInfo = new ProcessStartInfo("ffmpeg.exe", "-i 176d2819-f1da-44eb-b33b-94eb1448194b.mov");
        oInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
        oInfo.CreateNoWindow = true;
        oInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
        oInfo.RedirectStandardError = true;

        string output = string.Empty;
        StreamReader srOutput = null;

            //run the process
            Process proc = Process.Start(oInfo);
            proc.WaitForExit();
            srOutput = proc.StandardError;
            output = srOutput.ReadToEnd();
            proc.Close();

running from command line
ffmpeg.exe -i 176d2819-f1da-44eb-b33b-94eb1448194b.mov, getting an error as included in the below output
could not find codec parameters for stream 1 (Audio: none (apac / 0x63617061), 48000 Hz, 4 channels, 382 kb/s): unknown codec
Consider increasing the value for the 'analyzeduration' (0) and 'probesize' (5000000) options
[aist#0:1/none @ 0000029b0e1b0040] Guessed Channel Layout: 4.0
Input #0, mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2, from '176d2819-f1da-44eb-b33b-94eb1448194b.mov'
ffmpeg version N-117538-g9ce63e65d6-20241015 Copyright (c) 2000-2024 the FFmpeg developers
  built with gcc 14.2.0 (crosstool-NG 1.26.0.120_4d36f27)
  configuration: --prefix=/ffbuild/prefix --pkg-config-flags=--static --pkg-config=pkg-config --cross-prefix=x86_64-w64-mingw32- --arch=x86_64 --target-os=mingw32 --enable-gpl --enable-version3 --disable-debug --disable-w32threads --enable-pthreads --enable-iconv --enable-zlib --enable-libfreetype --enable-libfribidi --enable-gmp --enable-libxml2 --enable-lzma --enable-fontconfig --enable-libharfbuzz --enable-libvorbis --enable-opencl --disable-libpulse --enable-libvmaf --disable-libxcb --disable-xlib --enable-amf --enable-libaom --enable-libaribb24 --enable-avisynth --enable-chromaprint --enable-libdav1d --enable-libdavs2 --enable-libdvdread --enable-libdvdnav --disable-libfdk-aac --enable-ffnvcodec --enable-cuda-llvm --enable-frei0r --enable-libgme --enable-libkvazaar --enable-libaribcaption --enable-libass --enable-libbluray --enable-libjxl --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libopus --enable-librist --enable-libssh --enable-libtheora --enable-libvpx --enable-libwebp --enable-libzmq --enable-lv2 --enable-libvpl --enable-openal --enable-libopencore-amrnb --enable-libopencore-amrwb --enable-libopenh264 --enable-libopenjpeg --enable-libopenmpt --enable-librav1e --enable-librubberband --enable-schannel --enable-sdl2 --enable-libsoxr --enable-libsrt --enable-libsvtav1 --enable-libtwolame --enable-libuavs3d --disable-libdrm --enable-vaapi --enable-libvidstab --enable-vulkan --enable-libshaderc --enable-libplacebo --enable-libvvenc --enable-libx264 --enable-libx265 --enable-libxavs2 --enable-libxvid --enable-libzimg --enable-libzvbi --extra-cflags=-DLIBTWOLAME_STATIC --extra-cxxflags= --extra-libs=-lgomp --extra-ldflags=-pthread --extra-ldexeflags= --cc=x86_64-w64-mingw32-gcc --cxx=x86_64-w64-mingw32-g++ --ar=x86_64-w64-mingw32-gcc-ar --ranlib=x86_64-w64-mingw32-gcc-ranlib --nm=x86_64-w64-mingw32-gcc-nm --extra-version=20241015
  libavutil      59. 43.100 / 59. 43.100
  libavcodec     61. 22.100 / 61. 22.100
  libavformat    61.  9.100 / 61.  9.100
  libavdevice    61.  4.100 / 61.  4.100
  libavfilter    10.  6.100 / 10.  6.100
  libswscale      8.  6.100 /  8.  6.100
  libswresample   5.  4.100 /  5.  4.100
  libpostproc    58.  4.100 / 58.  4.100
[mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2 @ 000001b447c84e40] Could not find codec parameters for stream 1 (Audio: none (apac / 0x63617061), 48000 Hz, 4 channels, 382 kb/s): unknown codec
Consider increasing the value for the 'analyzeduration' (0) and 'probesize' (5000000) options
[aist#0:1/none @ 000001b44a6bf880] Guessed Channel Layout: 4.0
Input #0, mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2, from '176d2819-f1da-44eb-b33b-94eb1448194b.mov':
  Metadata:
    major_brand     : qt
    minor_version   : 0
    compatible_brands: qt
    creation_time   : 2024-10-14T07:34:17.000000Z
    com.apple.quicktime.full-frame-rate-playback-intent: 0
    com.apple.quicktime.make: Apple
    com.apple.quicktime.model: iPhone 16 Pro Max
    com.apple.quicktime.software: 18.0.1
    com.apple.quicktime.creationdate: 2024-10-14T16:18:36+1100
    com.apple.photos.originating.signature: AQMNJRMQrKK7im+Kjhixx6TqQyYm
  Duration: 00:00:32.60, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 15064 kb/s
  Stream #0:0[0x1](und): Audio: aac (LC) (mp4a / 0x6134706D), 48000 Hz, stereo, fltp, 130 kb/s (default)
    Metadata:
      creation_time   : 2024-10-14T07:34:17.000000Z
      handler_name    : Core Media Audio
      vendor_id       : [0][0][0][0]
  Stream #0:1[0x2](und): Audio: none (apac / 0x63617061), 48000 Hz, 4.0, 382 kb/s
    Metadata:
      creation_time   : 2024-10-14T07:34:17.000000Z
      handler_name    : Core Media Audio
      vendor_id       : [0][0][0][0]
  Stream #0:2[0x3](und): Video: h264 (High) (avc1 / 0x31637661), yuv420p(tv, bt709, progressive), 1920x1080, 14464 kb/s, 30 fps, 30 tbr, 600 tbn (default)
    Metadata:
      creation_time   : 2024-10-14T07:34:17.000000Z
      handler_name    : Core Media Video
      vendor_id       : [0][0][0][0]
      encoder         : H.264
  Stream #0:3[0x4](und): Data: none (mebx / 0x7862656D), 0 kb/s (default)
    Metadata:
      creation_time   : 2024-10-14T07:34:17.000000Z
      handler_name    : Core Media Metadata
  Stream #0:4[0x5](und): Data: none (mebx / 0x7862656D), 0 kb/s (default)
    Metadata:
      creation_time   : 2024-10-14T07:34:17.000000Z
      handler_name    : Core Media Metadata
  Stream #0:5[0x6](und): Data: none (mebx / 0x7862656D), 21 kb/s (default)
    Metadata:
      creation_time   : 2024-10-14T07:34:17.000000Z
      handler_name    : Core Media Metadata
  Stream #0:6[0x7](und): Data: none (mebx / 0x7862656D), 48 kb/s (default)
    Metadata:
      creation_time   : 2024-10-14T07:34:17.000000Z
      handler_name    : Core Media Metadata
  Stream #0:7[0x8](und): Data: none (mebx / 0x7862656D), 2 kb/s (default)
    Metadata:
      creation_time   : 2024-10-14T07:34:17.000000Z
      handler_name    : Core Media Metadata
  Stream #0:8[0x9](und): Data: none (mebx / 0x7862656D), 0 kb/s (default)
    Metadata:
      creation_time   : 2024-10-14T07:34:17.000000Z
      handler_name    : Core Media Metadata

This error does not happen on all files but only on a handful of files.

FFmpeg may not be compatible with certain files. Could you share your test files?

I resolved it by putting a time in the WaitForExit property
 Process proc = Process.Start(oInfo);
        proc.WaitForExit(20000);
        srOutput = proc.StandardError;
        output = srOutput.ReadToEnd();
        proc.Close();

It exists after 20 seconds if it's stalled which is enough time to get the media info and even on the files that have the error, it still has the media info
